# Custom folder icon not showing on remote computer

Tags: windows, remote-access

I copied a movie to a 256gb usb drive. Put it into a separate folder and changed the folder icon, stored this icon in a separate hidden folder. It works/looks fine on my laptop, however on another computer the new folder icon does not appear, only the standard default windows icon is displayed. all files are present but not showing up, can someone tell me why, I would appreciate it! Thanks

Comment: Hey Tubtech, welcome to Superuser. There are a few things you can do that will help you get a useful answer. One is to change your title to be more descriptive, but still succinct. There are a *lot* of "USB Drive Issues" here and people get bored of answering the same questions over and over. Try phrasing the title as the central question to your inquiry. Also, your exact problem is somewhat unclear. Are you saying the files do not show up at all on the other computer (but you are somehow able to verify they are present)? Please edit your question with any additional details.

Answer (score 2):

The icon used for the folder is defined inside the folder itself by the hidden file
`desktop.ini`, containing a line that may look like:

```
IconResource=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll,27
```

As the file specified in the `IconResource` directive is stored on the local
computer, a remote computer may not be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

When you right click and customize the icon, windows puts the full path to the icon in the ini file. If you copy that folder the ini file does not automatically update and now the path is broken and you have no icon.
But If you

1. Put the icon file into the folder you are customizing
2. Edit the ini file to remove the full path (e.g. change it to IconResource=icon.ico,0)
   Now, when you copy the folder the path is still correct and your icon still works.
   Then set the icon file to hidden, so it does not clutter your folder

There is also a program called folderico that will do this for you, so you don't have to go unhiding and hiding system files